# Drawing line arrow from origin/destination coordinates fields using Geometry Generator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, polyline-creation, geometry-generator, connection

From the following table structure with the fields `"ORIG_LATITUDE", "ORIG_LONGITUDE", "DEST_LATITUDE", "DEST_LONGITUDE"`:

[image]

I clarify that the field names describe with their prefix the coordinates belonging to the Origin (ORIG) and Destination (DEST).

I would like to draw an arrow with the `make_line` function that connects the point defined by the fields of each record `"ORIG_LATITUDE", "ORIG_LONGITUDE"` with the fields `"DEST_LATITUDE", "DEST_LONGITUDE"`, as shown in this image

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
make_line(
   make_point("ORIG_LON", "ORIG_LAT"),
   make_point("DEST_LON", "DEST_LAT")
   )
```

---

If you have a data-only table, without geometry, there are two options: load the table as a point layer first (as recommended by @J.R) or, if you want to avoid this, [create directly a new Virtual Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers), containing the lines.

The query in the virtual layer looks like this:

```sql
select make_line(make_point(t.ORIG_LON, t.ORIG_LAT), make_point(t.DEST_LON, t.DEST_LAT))
from your_table_name as t
```

You can then export/save the virtual layer to make the resulting lines permanent (not depending on the table any more).

Comment: I understand the idea of this expression, but I understand that it works for a layer with point geometry. In the case of my project, the difficulty I find is that the data source is a table. How can I apply this expression to a table? Do I have to transform the table into a point layer and then apply the expression?

Comment: Yes to use the geometry generator you need to have vector data, a single table wont work. As you have coordinate you may load the table as a point layer first then use @Babel expression

Comment: Indeed, thanks @J.R, it's exactly as you say. Another option is to create a virtual layer to avoid loading the initial table as points layer, see updated answer.

Comment: @Babel doesn't the make_point use (x, y) or (Lon, Lat) rather than (Lat, Lon) ?

Comment: @J.R indeed, you're completely right. I was using dummy coordinates and was so focused on the syntax that this indeed very basic mistake skipped my attention. Good you drew our attention to this, I corrected the answer.